# The name of provided capability "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu" is not defined

Tags: tycho

Using Tycho 0.21 I get an error message regarding the name of a provided capability "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu" not being defined. I searched our code base for the string "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu" and only found it inside a P2 update site which I disabled only to get the same error message again.

The error occurs when using a POM with packaging "pom" that includes several modules:

```
<modules>
  <module>some-module</module>
</module>
```

It worked earlier using a heavily modified version of Tycho 0.8. We are currently trying to switch to Tycho 0.21 where one of the challenges is moving from a file system based target platform ("Installation" in Eclipse) to using update sites.

Can anybody provide hints to this message?

```
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:the name of provided capability "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu" is not defined -> [Help 1]
[artifact:mvn] org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:the name of provided capability "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu" is not defined
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[artifact:mvn]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[artifact:mvn]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[artifact:mvn]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[artifact:mvn] Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:the name of provided capability "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu" is not defined
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.ProvidedCapability.<init>(ProvidedCapability.java:35)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.MetadataFactory.createProvidedCapability(MetadataFactory.java:429)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.AbstractDependenciesAction.perform(AbstractDependenciesAction.java:83)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.Publisher$ArtifactProcess.run(Publisher.java:207)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.Publisher.publish(Publisher.java:237)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.AbstractMetadataGenerator.publish(AbstractMetadataGenerator.java:118)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.AbstractMetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(AbstractMetadataGenerator.java:58)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.DefaultDependencyMetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(DefaultDependencyMetadataGenerator.java:30)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.publisher.DefaultDependencyMetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(DefaultDependencyMetadataGenerator.java:1)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.getDependencyMetadata(P2DependencyResolver.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.setupProjects(P2DependencyResolver.java:126)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.setupProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:87)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:70)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[artifact:mvn]  ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by a product without ID. Check that all your *.product files specify an ID on the Overview tab of the Product Configuration Editor.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to find out that I haven't discovered your answer for several years. I haven't been working with Eclipse and Tycho for the last couple of years so I can't even try out your suggestion. Still, thank you for taking the time to answer the question. (I don't know if I should accept your answer or not? The upvotes seem to imply that the answer is correct?)

Comment: "Accepted" means that the answer worked for you as asker. So if you can't verify the answer, you should probably leave it to the community to decide on the quality of the answer via votes.

Comment: And hopefully, we'll see you more active in the community in the future :-)